# Openstack: hostname is appended by "novalocal"

Tags: openstack, heat

I have made a heat template that starts up some servers and installs puppet. In the heat template I have put for the servers their hostname by doing:

```
properties:
    name: dir
```

Some servers actually gets their hostname, but there are a few that gets their hostname appended by ".novalocal".

An example for a server I have

```
properties:
    name: server1
```

actual hostname: `server1.novalocal`

Any idea what cause this? I am at a total loss.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reference:
[Neutron Network DNS Suffix via DHCP](http://lists.openstack.org/pipermail/openstack/2017-March/019000.html)

Nova appends the default domain name `.novalocal` to the hostname. This can be resolved by setting `dhcp_domain` to an empty string in nova.conf on the Control node.

```
# This option allows you to specify the domain for the DHCP server.
#
# Possible values:
#
# * Any string that is a valid domain name.
#
#dhcp_domain = novalocal
dhcp_domain =
```

FYI, As @Дмитрий Работягов mentioned, this option has been moved to [api] section, here is the change [480616](https://review.opendev.org/c/openstack/nova/+/480616/14) on Openstack Code-Review system.

Comment: It's not actually deprecated since 15.0.0. It jsut has been moved from [DEFAULT] to [api] section of nova.conf.

Comment: Thanks for sharing, I've updated the answer.